# NameError: global name 'create_engine' is not defined [when trying to create a SQLAlchemyJobStore]

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, scheduler, apscheduler

I am trying to add a `SQLAlchemyJobStore` job store (and make it the `default` job store) and store some jobs on it. I am running `mysql` which has a database named `jobstore`.

I have the following program which tries to open a `SQLAlchemyJobStore` job store to the `mysql` db that is running:

```
# sqlalchemy.py 
from sqlalchemy import *
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy_store import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def alarm(time):
    print('Alarm! This alarm was scheduled at %s.' % time)

_aps_config = {'standalone': 'True'}
_dbURL = 'mysql://root:<root-password>@localhost/jobstore'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    scheduler = Scheduler(_aps_config)
    scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=_dbURL), 'default')

    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_date_job(alarm, alarm_time, name='alarm1', args=[datetime.now()])
    print 'alarms added: ', alarm_time

    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=15)
    scheduler.add_date_job(alarm, alarm_time, name='alarm2', args=[datetime.now()])
    print 'alarms added: ', alarm_time

    alarm_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=20)
    scheduler.add_date_job(alarm, alarm_time, name='alarm3', args=[datetime.now()])
    print 'alarms added: ', alarm_time

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()
        pass
```

When trying to run the above code I see the following:

```
NameError: global name 'create_engine' is not defined

$ python sqlalchemy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlalchemy.py", line 19, in <module>
    scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=_dbURL), 'default')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/APScheduler-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy_store.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.engine = create_engine(url)
NameError: global name 'create_engine' is not defined
$
```

I see `"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/APScheduler-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy_store.py"`, the `__init__` is trying to `create_engine` and its failing.

```
 20 class SQLAlchemyJobStore(JobStore):
 21     def __init__(self, url=None, engine=None, tablename='apscheduler_jobs',
 22                  metadata=None, pickle_protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL):
 23         self.jobs = []
 24         self.pickle_protocol = pickle_protocol
 25 
 26         if engine:
 27             self.engine = engine
 28         elif url:
 29             self.engine = create_engine(url)
```

What is going wrong here?! In other words, how do I create a `SQLAlchemyJobStore` using `APScheduler` and successfully store the jobs on them? Any example/code-snippet would be a great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem no problem in your code. I tried to run it and it successfully completes with the following output:

```
python jobstore.py
alarms added:  2013-02-07 10:31:10.234000
alarms added:  2013-02-07 10:31:15.240000
alarms added:  2013-02-07 10:31:20.240000
```

The only change I made was updating `_dbURL = 'sqlite:///:memory:'` to use sqlite engine.

Please check do you have sqlalchemy installed and it can be found in PYTHONPATH by your script.
Run the following code in python console or better add it at the beginning of your script and check the output.

```
import sqlalchemy
print sqlalchemy.__version__
```

**UPDATE**
I reread your post and realized that my test code had one more difference - I created file with another name: jobstore.py

I tried to rename file to sqlalchemy.py and got same exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/stackoverflow/so/sqlalchemy.py", line 22, in <module>
    scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=_dbURL), 'default')
  File "C:\Progs\Python27\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\jobstores\sqlalchemy_store.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.engine = create_engine(url)
NameError: global name 'create_engine' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Basically the problem is that your python script name has same name as sqlalchemy module name thus python loads your scripts first and cannot access sqlalchemy code.

Try to rename script name to something other then `sqlalchemy.py` - this would help if you have sqlalchemy module installed.

Comment: you are correct; The same has been discussed on the APScheduler google groups and a gentleman from the community highlighted the same! Thanks! +1

Comment: Thanks you saved a day